# Updating a Table While Inserting Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a large table with billions of records, let's call it `dbo.Events`. It has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events
(
   Id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key,
   [timestamp] datetime not null,
   serial_number int not null, -- device id
   val1 float, -- device value 1
   val2 float, -- device value 2
   val3 float, -- device value 3
   [status] tinyint -- processing status flag
)
```

There are 3 operations taking place on this table:

1- **Insert**: data is being fed to this table by and external `SSIS` package, that I do not have control over (Using `OLE DB Destination` component -> fast load, no locking on the table).

2- **Select**: Since I need to process the entire table (in batches due to the size), I have a buffer table of the same structure. Periodically, I select some amount of records (e.g. **500K**) into the buffer, process the data on the buffer, and then save the result somewhere else. The select query is:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.EventBuffer (Id, [timestamp], serial_number, val1, val2, val3)
SELECT TOP 500000 Evt.Id, [timestamp], Evt.serial_number, Evt.val1, Evt.val2, Evt.val3
FROM dbo.Events Evt WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN dbo.Equipments Eq ON Evt.serial_number = Eq.serial_number -- Joined with equipment table to only retrieve selected equipments
Where Evt.timestamp >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' and Evt.timestamp <= '2099-12-31 23:59:59.999' and [status] IS NULL
```

3- **Update**: Lastly, I would like to update the `status` flag in the `dbo.Events` table, for the records that I processed in the current batch, so it is ignored in the next run. The query to update the table is written as:

```
UPDATE Evt
SET Evt.[status] = 1 
FROM dbo.Events Evt WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN dbo.EventBuffer buf ON Evt.Id = Buf.Id
WHERE Evt.[status] IS NULL
```

What I have noticed, is that the update process takes too long, in such a way that the `insert` performance is hit badly, and sometimes fails completely.

My questions would be:

1. Conceptually, is this design feasible? if not, how to improve it ?
2. How to enhance the update process, so the other processes are not affected ?
3. Any thoughts on indexing ?

Comment: Better reduce the indexes as indexes will be good for select queries, but it will add performance issues when writing and updating.
try merge which will do insert or update based on condition. Upsert table  also has the same technique. 
use No lock when selecting data. Batch processing is a good solution as you can read more on lambda architecture. It is better to process by paging data so that you can improve your performance rather than applying it as a whole.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). It is obvious that you think it is magic and consequence-free, as it is obvious you have no idea what it does. It makes no sense to apply it to a table that you update. But much depends on the execution plans and identifying what causes "takes too long". And much of that depends on your indexing - which you did not post. How do you know it is the UPDATE logic and not the "process 500k rows" logic?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) "A" is for "Events"? "B" is for "Equipment"? Also, don't dump a `TOP` in your query if you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause. That will cause the `TOP` *x* rows returned will the *x* arbitrary rows; meaning that they could be different *every* time you run the query.

Comment: @Gudwlk I think upsert here is not valid. As I stated the insert is executed by a separate process that is out of my control. Rest of the points: agree :)

Comment: @khidirsanosi yeah, I jsut gave all possibilities. I use upset when working with some data. or this scenario, we need more information. atleast query plan to see how it is.

Comment: The DB structure really sounds horrible... one way or the other updating and inserting the same table from different process will sooner or later cause headache... what we usually do in this kind of Scenario (or better: how your process would look like in our process): one process writes into the events table. As soon as the processing of the data starts, this table is renamed and a new empty table is created - this way the insert process can continue. Now you do whatever required on the renamed table and afterwards move the data to a archive table - this one will sroe the billion records.

Comment: @SMor I will provide the index info as well as the execution plans later, but simply to answer your question, I disabled the update part, and everything runs fast. Enabling back will introduce the issue again. Sounds inconvenient maybe, but this is what it is.

Comment: @Tyron78 thanks for explaining your approach, but this assumes the two processes are synchronized some how, otherwise you might run into a scenario where you rename the table, but the insert process hasn't yet completed, or ?

Comment: @khidirsanosi The processes are not synchronized. Our inserting-process (file import) runs every 10 minutes or so... The rename and creation of the empty table work pretty fast. I would have to check, but I think the empty table is created first with some appendix to it and afterwards two renames (ImportTable to ImportTable_work and ImportTable_new to ImportTable) are executed.... we didn't face conflicts by now

Comment: Just a quick suggestion: 1) If you process all the rows between min(Id) and max(Id), you could rewrite the update as `UPDATE Evt SET Evt.[status] = 1  FROM dbo.Events Evt WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Evt.Id between @MinId and @MaxId and [status] IS NULL`. 2) If that's not the case, you could try to transform the inner join intro an exists() condition such as: `UPDATE Evt SET Evt.[status] = 1 FROM dbo.Events Evt WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) 1 Id from dbo.EventBuffer buf WHERE Evt.Id = Buf.Id) AND Evt.[status] IS NULL`